# WordPress website signature is showing "not secured"

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, relative-path, absolute-path

My problem is simple, I have a WordPress website included with certificate. But still its showing **"not secured"**. Is this because my site is making numerous **HTTP requests**? If that's the problem I tried resolving by adding a filter in my **functions.php**. The filter looks like this:

```
function switch_to_relative_url($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt)
{
$imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size);
$relativeurl = wp_make_link_relative($imageurl[0]);   
$html = str_replace($imageurl[0],$relativeurl,$html);

return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','switch_to_relative_url',10,8);
```

I also tried replacing **wp_get_attachment_image_src** to **wp_get_attachment_thumb_url**. But all these lines of codes have no effect. My site seems to still make same HTTP requests. I focused more on images because they are the direct requests from the site.

Please suggest me what is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

To know why the site shows "not secured" try this website www.whynopadlock.com it helps identify the issue easily, also a common issue would be your wordpress settings, adding https to the url in the settings tab may help, if the site is "not secured" because of mixed content (like images loading over http) you could use a plugin to fix it for you, search for "SSL nsecure content fix" plugins

Comment: Thank you, _www.whynopadlock.com_ really helped me a lot. Because of mixed content the "not secured" sign is showing. Please can you further suggest me useful fliters or plugin to change all the absolute urls to relative urls?

Comment: "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" would do the job